# the+noun+of +noun

Tags: articles

> 1-Therefore, ***the*** extraction of optimized thermodynamic parameters from various publications is required.

In the above sentence, is the definite article "the" really necessary?
When are they required in the case of ****the**+noun+of+noun** sentences?

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/257327/118547) concerning the choice between "zero" and "the".

Comment: You could include definite articles before either, neither, or both of ***extraction*** and ***optimized***. Stylistically I'd say it's a bit weak to include *both* - but syntactically, all 4 permutations are perfectly valid.

Comment: Can I remove the definite article before extraction since extraction is an uncountable noun? Will the sentence be wrong?

Comment: I think whether "the" is used depends on whether the extraction and the parameters have been mentioned before, and so on whether they are definite in the mind of the writer.